# How to raise maxBodyLength limit in package follow-redirects

Tags: node.js, npm

Using the NPM package 'googleapis' to upload a video to Youtube, I have the following error:

```
Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit
```

How can I raise the limit manually to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the following code before starting the upload to Youtube:

```
const followRedirects = require('follow-redirects');
followRedirects.maxRedirects = 10;
followRedirects.maxBodyLength = 500 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 GB
```

It imports the package 'followRedirects' and set the limit to 500GB.